# how to do this operation in numpy (chaining of tiling operation)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to do fast generation of numpy array, possibly without passing through python.

I want to build an 1D index numpy array that would take this as an input:

`[2,3]` and this `[2,4]` and would return this

```
 [0,1,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
```

Explanation:

I iterate from 0 to 2 (so [0,1] array) and repeat it 2 times : `[0,1,0,1]`

Then I iterate from 0 to 3 (so [0,1,2] array) and repeat it 4 times : `[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]`
Then I flattened everything.

Is there a way to do this fully in numpy?
For now I'm building each table separately in numpy by using np.tile() and flattening everything afterwards but I feel like there is a more efficient way that would only translate to C functions calls and no python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
def cycles(spec):
    steps = np.repeat(*spec)
    ps = steps.cumsum()
    psj = np.zeros(ps[-1], int)
    psj[ps[:-1]] = steps[:-1]
    return np.arange(ps[-1]) - psj.cumsum()
```

Demo:

```
>>> cycles(((2,3),(2,4)))
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks!However it's failing for some combinations:
a = [4, 0, 1,0]
b = [35, 72, 5, 72]
cycles(a,b)

I think it has to do with the 0 at the end of 'a' array

Comment: @lezebulon Rather pathological example and also easy to address. Just filter out the 0 positions. For example, add the line `steps = steps[steps.astype(bool)]` after the first line of the function body.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if this is what you want; here each tuple in the call to func() contains first the range and then the repeat.

```
import numpy


def func(tups):
    Arr = numpy.empty(numpy.sum([ele[0] * ele[1] for ele in tups]), dtype=int)
    i = 0
    for ele in tups:
        Arr[i:i + ele[0] * ele[1]] = numpy.tile(numpy.arange(ele[0]), ele[1])
        i += ele[0] * ele[1]
    return Arr


arr = func([(2, 3), (3, 4)])
print(arr)
# [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
```